# Custom Sort Based On Referenced Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-7.0

Please consider these data:

```
Id           F1          F2          Ref_ID
------------------------------------------- 
1            Nima        35           Null
2            Eli         33           Null
3            Arian       5            1
4            Ava         1            1
5            Arsha       3            2
6            Rozhan      30           1
7            Zhina       20           2
```

I want to sort this table like this result:

```
Id           F1          F2          Ref_ID
------------------------------------------- 
1            Nima        35           Null
3            Arian       5            1
4            Ava         1            1    
6            Rozhan      30           1
2            Eli         33           Null
5            Arsha       3            2
7            Zhina       20           2
```

the refrenced records should place under the reference record based on Id ascending.

How I can do this using `LINQ` or `SQL`. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I do join but I couldn't generate result with join in `LINQ`

Comment: I haven't got a clue what your sort order is. Why is Nima before the items with Ref_Id 1, and why is Eli after them?

Comment: Show us some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL you could sort it by using a `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` for the Ref_id and the Id.

And an `IIF` or a `CASE WHEN` to make sure the parent id comes first in the same group of Ref_id.

```
SELECT Id, F1, F2, Ref_ID
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY COALESCE(Ref_ID, Id), IIF(Ref_ID IS NULL, 0, 1), Id;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9dcc818f146b5b903e9bd22c71d8c9a)*

Comment: You can remove the IIF returning 0 or 1 and simply sort by id only :)

Comment: @PratikBhavsar That would be enough for the sample set.  And if Ref_ID is a foreign key on Id then you could assume that the parent always has the lowest Id in a group.  But that IIF makes sure of it, even if the parent doesn't have the lowest Id. :)

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed that it is a foreign key and the parent id is always going to be lowest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simple solution:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    F1,
    F2,
    Ref_ID
FROM 
    @Table
ORDER BY 
    ISNULL(Ref_ID,ID), ID
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works but I don't understand `ISNULL` in order clause. It seems it returns `Id` or `Ref_ID` instead of their values.Is it true?

Comment: @Arian It returns ID if Ref_ID is null else Ref_ID. Imagine it as a calculated column. In your case, the column will look like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, you can do it like this:

```
from i in data
orderby i.Ref_ID ?? i.Id
select i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add an extra column in the query, and sort on that column

```
select t.*
from   ( select Id,
                F1,
                F2,
                Ref_ID,
                coalesce(Ref_ID, Id) as RefID_or_Id, 
                iif(Ref_ID is null, 0, 1) as Ref_ID_0_or_1
        from  YourTable
       ) t
order by t.RefID_or_Id,
         t.Ref_ID_0_or_1,   
         t.Id
```

In case your table is large, you should test wich of the solutions here performs the best for you

Comment: Sorry about that but you are unnecessarily using sub query and draining performance, you can simply use that expression for the calculated column in order by clause. Hope this helps.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar I am not sure if this is true. Using `coalesce` and `iff` in a where clause means sqlserver cannot use an index. I have found that this way a query can actually perform better. That is why I also wrote he needs to test for performance, since it can depend on his table schema which we dont know

Comment: @PratikBhavsar Also, using a `subquery` like this will not drain any performance at all, the only thing that can drain performance are the functions called. That is so in each answer here. I am simply offering an alternative when the performance is bad in one of the other answers.

Comment: Exactly, we don't know the schema so I decided not to worry about indexes. Anyway, thanks for letting know.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar That still leaves me wondering why I got a downvote